# MySQL Trigger - Compare Values of two different tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Im currently struggling with the implementation of a trigger in MySQL.
My scenario is the following:

There are two databases (*emailregistration & answers*) with a different set of ids as the primary key. Therefore I want to identify the correct row that needs to be updated using the email adress as the identifier.(which is identical in both tables)
I want to start a trigger, when the database "registration" is updated. This trigger then updates a value in "users". (represented as *confirmed/unsubscribed*)

The problem from my understanding is, that there is no check for the correct row. My code below is taking directly form phpmyadmin. In its current form the statement fills up the answers database with empty rows and changes the column confirmed/unsubscribed as desired but its not identifying the right row.

```
    AFTER
    UPDATE
    ------
    INSERT INTO answers (confirmed, unsubscribed)
    SELECT emailregistration.confirmed, emailregistration.unsubscribed
    FROM emailregistration
    WHERE emailregistration.email = email
    -----
    root@localhost

    *This should translate into the following trigger code:*

    CREATE TRIGGER DOI 
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON emailregistration
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO answers (confirmed, unsubscribed)
    SELECT emailregistration.confirmed, emailregistration.unsubscribed
    FROM emailregistration
    WHERE emailregistration.email = email
    END;
```

I hope I described my problem accurately. Feel free to ask questions if I didnt.
Thanks for your help, its greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a trigger I would expect to see reference to OLD. and/or NEW. values (depending on trigger type) 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Please add the rest of your trigger code.

Comment: @P.Salmon Added the trigger code, I have read through this page of the docs just now.  From my understanding that only helps when referencing to the updated cells. How do I go on about comparing column "email" in emailregistration to column "email" in answers to make sure it addreses the right column?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am baffled by the question. You say you'This trigger then updates a value in "users". ' but there's no users table in the trigger what's more you are inserting to answers not updating which is at odds with your stated requirement. And the query is vague what table does the email column to the right of the = sign belong? Is there in fact only 1 record in the answer table per email?

Comment: Well, maybe Im kind of explaining it really complicated. 
The "registration" table has the following 3 columns (email, subscribed, confirmed) and the "users" table has the same 3 colums. Now I want to compare the value of the email column in the two databases and assign the values of confirmed and unsubscribed of registration) to the columns in users. Does that make sense? The table to the left belongs to "answers". Thats where its getting even more complicated, technically its possible more than just one time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
drop table if exists r,u;
create table r(email varchar(3), subscribed varchar(1), confirmed varchar(1));
create table u(email varchar(3), subscribed varchar(1), confirmed varchar(1));

insert into r (email) values('aaa'),('bbb');
insert into u (email,subscribed,confirmed) values('aaa','x','x'),('bbb','y','y');
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER t 
AFTER UPDATE
ON r
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     update u 
        set  subscribed = new.subscribed,
              confirmed = new.confirmed
        where email = new.email;

END $$
delimiter ;

update r set subscribed = 'n' where email = 'aaa';

select * from r;

+-------+------------+-----------+
| email | subscribed | confirmed |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| aaa   | n          | NULL      |
| bbb   | NULL       | NULL      |
+-------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from u;

+-------+------------+-----------+
| email | subscribed | confirmed |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| aaa   | n          | NULL      |
| bbb   | y          | y         |
+-------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this is not the model you have then add it to the question together with expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this, I will test it tomorrow!